# array_reduce to use dynamic variables pass in second function

Tags: php, array-reduce

I have below `$test` array

```
        Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 3
            [stock_id] => _PHONE
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 3
            [stock_id] => 102
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 4
            [stock_id] => _PHONE
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 3
            [stock_id] => 102
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 4
            [stock_id] => _PHONE
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 6
            [stock_id] => _PHONE
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 2
            [stock_id] => 102
        )

)
```

and to sum same stock_id keys to one, i use below functions:

```
function sum($array, $key){
    isset($array[$key['stock_id']]) ? $array[$key['stock_id']]['quantity'] += $key['quantity'] : $array[$key['stock_id']] = $key;  
    return $array;
};

//merge same stock_id and sum the quantity same stock id
$sum_same_stock_id = array_reduce($test, "sum");
```

and the result went well like below:

$sum_same_stock_id:

```
Array
(
    [_PHONE] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 17
            [stock_id] => _PHONE
        )

    [102] => Array
        (
            [quantity] => 8
            [stock_id] => 102
        )

)
```

So the question here is, I wanted to pass an dynamic keys values not just fixed values `stock_id` & `quantity` in `sum` function above. Have tried variety ways but still can't figured out the way. And can we put those functions into class as well?

Any advise is appreciated!

Comment: `stock_id` at index `0` and `quantity` index at `1` will remain same ?

Comment: No, for example if stock_id & quantity name in beginning array has changed to different names like "amount" & "stock_code". And then in sum function, I just need to input dynamic variable that is like function sum($array, $key, $amount, $id), where $amount & $id are "amount" & "stock_code" name rather than manually replace "amount" & "stock_code" repeatedly inside "sum" function.

Comment: @SonDang, have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the "use" function for the callback?

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php